# How do I use the default NSMenu named "File Menu" to get the path of the selected file?

Tags: macos, file, path, menu, nsmenu

I would like to allow a user to use the file menu to select a file in the "Open..." selection in the "File Menu", and allow me to get the path of the file that was selected by the user.

Comment: Have you solved this? Do you mean to use Objective-C or would an AppleScript (GUI scripting) solution be ok?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think iOS allows file system access this way.

Comment: It's mac osx, sorry for not specifying.